# Detecting when a custom UIButton has been pressed

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, subclass

I have created a custom UIButton (UIButton subclass) for my application. Within this button's implementation, how would I alter the background color when it is pressed? (It should revert to it's normal background when depressed. I am currently using Core Graphics to draw a gradient background.)

I have tried branching in `drawRect:` (checking for `self.selected` and `self.highlighted`, but no change occurs because `drawRect` is not being called on the touch event.

Any suggestions or code samples are appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try calling `[self setNeedsRedraw]` in your touch event.

---

Asker provided a solution based on this answer and the comments below.

**Solution**

Used:

```
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonDepressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside | UIControlEventTouchCancel];
```

Where the selectors are custom functions that perform the background change.

Comment: I need to capture this touch event within the button's implementation in order to set its background color.

Comment: You can always add yourself as a listener to your own touch events.  Try `[self addTarget: self action: @selector(setNeedsRedraw) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];`

Comment: Thank you. Using `addTarget` on `self` worked. I added my actual solution to your answer.